# How to align Angular UI Typeahead to the right

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm using angular-ui-bootstrap in an RTL language website (in Arabic). Typeahead aligns all results to the left by default. How to change it to right?

This is mentioned in the angular-ui-bootstrap website:

> The $uibPosition service provides a set of DOM utilities used internally to absolute-position an element in relation to another element (tooltips, popovers, typeaheads etc...).

I couldn't figure it out. Any examples out there?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
 .rtl .dropdown-menu{
     float:right;
     position:inherit;
  }
```